# Windows 7 "sunny" network icon

Tags: windows-7, gui, windows-shell

In Windows 7, I sometimes see this "sun" icon overlay in the networking tray icon:

[image: the sunny network icon overlay]

What does it mean?

Bonus points: cite docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that wireless networks are ***available.***  But you have yet to connect to one.

> [View and connect to available wireless networks - Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/View-and-connect-to-available-wireless-networks)

Screenshot of video overlay in the URL above:

[image]

Comment: ...Enlightened?

Answer (score 4):

It means you are not connected to any wireless network.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/View-and-connect-to-available-wireless-networks

Comment: one second! :-)

Comment: That will never happen again!