# what is this orange ball over my wireless network icon in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

What is the orange ball on the wireless icon

And why does it have no green ticks in the icon at the very bottom(with the orange ball on it).  But it has green ticks in the popup for Network R8 (the one I am connected to)?

[image]

Comment: This is a visual glitch that sometimes occurs when Windows doesn't update the icon. The Ball shows that there are Wireless Networks nearby that you could connect to. This shouldn't show as you are actually connected to the " ______R8" network.

Comment: @harley_woop is the lack of green lights in the icon below also a visual glitch?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. It should show as connected, but it isn't. That icon should only appear when you are not connected to any networks, but you can. It will update at some point AFAIK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 “sunny” network icon](http://superuser.com/questions/227793/windows-7-sunny-network-icon).

Answer (score 1):

I usually see this blob icon appear if there are either of the following two conditions present:

- captive portal "further information needed", or
- no internet access (ie, wifi is live, but nothing past it is)

Comment: I have internet access though, so it's not either of those.

Answer (score -1):

What fixed this problem for me was a simple System Restore in Windows 7.
Open Start Menu, type 'system restore' in search box. Click on System Restore. When pop up appears, click on 'show more restore points'.
From the list select a restore date that you know came before you had the problem. Hit 'Next' and follow the prompts to restore. Hey Presto! Job done,

Comment: This seems like the nuclear option